# Magento 2 Get Seller's address from the Item/Product that is added to your cart

Tags: product, magento2.2, shopping-cart, sellers-dashboard

For example in order to get total qty in the cart, the following code can be used:

```
$quote->getItemsQty();
```

For example, in order to get product details in the cart, the following code can be used:

```
$productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($productInfo as $item){
   echo $item->getProductId();
   echo $item->getName();
   echo $item->getSku();
   echo $item->getQty();
   echo $item->getPrice();
}
```

So in order to get seller's details of that particular product that is in your cart, how can I fetch seller's information such as his name or his city through that product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's seller information?

Comment: Well regarding seller information Its depends on extension. Its not default so nobody can answer it without playing extension code.

Comment: Seller's city for example or seller's name

Comment: @BernedettePerera, Are you using any custom extension for seller ?

Comment: @vivek, No Im not using any custom extension.

Comment: Not Sure what you have written for seller's information. but May be you can dump `$item`it should contain information you need. EG. `var_dump($item->getData()); die();`

Comment: What do you mean by Seller here? Are you using any marketplace extension?